# COM Reference Counting Questions

Tags: c++, com

I am writing code that utilizes COM interfaces.  I am basing my code on examples that I have found online.  I do not want to utilize smart pointers in this case because I want to understand the basics of COM and not just have a smart pointer class do all of the work for me.

In order to frame my questions, let's assume I have a class similar to the following:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private:
        IUnknown *m_pUnknown;

    public:
        TestClass();
        void AssignValue();
}

TestClass::TestClass()
{
    m_pUnknown = NULL;
}

void TestClass::AssignValue()
{
    IUnknown *pUnknown  = NULL;

    //Assign value to pUnknown here - not relevant to my questions

    m_pUnknown = pUnknown;

    pUnknown->Release();
}
```

Now on to my specific questions.

1)  The examples I've seen to not use `AddRef()` when initializing a value, such as in the class constructor.  Does the `AddRef()` happen  "automatically" behind the scenes when a COM pointer is first assigned a value?

2)  Although my code example does not show it, it is my understanding that in the `AssignValue()` method, when you assign a second value to overwrite the value of `pUnknown` (originally set in the class constructor), `Release()` is automatically called.  After assigning the new value to `pUnknown` its reference count stands at zero. I need to call `pUnknown->AddRef()` immediately after the reassignment.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: When using raw com pointers addref and release are never automatically called for you.

Comment: `*m_pUnknown = *pUnknown` makes no sense. You are just slicing `IUnknown` instance, which has no members, so it's a no-op at best. Besides, `m_pUnknown` is `NULL` (at least initially) and cannot be dereferenced (and when you try, you'd likely crash). You want something like `if (m_pUnknown) { m_pUnknown->Release(); } m_pUnknown = pUnknown;`

Comment: `AddRef` likely implicitly happens in "Assign value to pUnknown here - not relevant to my questions" part (which happens to be relevant to your question, contrary to your assurance). Most of the ways by which you might obtain a COM pointer (e.g. `CoCreateInstance`) would produce one that's already suitably `AddRef`ed.

Comment: *"overwrite the value of `pUnknown` (originally set in the class constructor),"* `pUnknown` is a local variable in `AssignValue`. It is certainly not set, nor even exists, in the class constructor. *"`Release()` is automatically called."* No it is not. Smart pointers would have done that - but you are deliberately not using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes: I assume we are ignoring exceptions for simplicity here. If this was for real, you would want to use smart pointers to help keep things straight in the presence of exceptions. Similarly, I am not worrying about proper copying or destruction of instances of your example class or multi-threading. (Your raw pointers cannot be used from different threads as simply as you might assume.)

First, You need to make any necessary calls to COM. The only way anything might happen "automatically" behind the scenes would be if you were using smart pointers to do them.

1) The examples you refer to have to be getting their COM interface pointers from somewhere. This would be by making COM calls, e.g., CoCreateInstance() and QueryInterface(). These calls are passed the address of your raw pointer and set that raw pointer to the appropriate value. If they weren't also implicitly AddRef'ed, the reference count might be 0 and COM could delete the associated COM object before your program could do anything about it. So such COM calls must include an implicit AddRef() on your behalf. You are responsible for a Release() to match this implicit AddRef() that you instigated with one of these other calls.

2a) Raw pointers are raw pointers. Their value is garbage until you arrange for them to be set to something valid. In particular, assigning a value to one will NOT auto-magically call a function. Assigning to a raw pointer to an interface does not call Release() - you need to do that at the appropriate time. In your post, it appears that you are "overwriting" a raw pointer that had previously been set to NULL, hence there was no existing COM interface instance in the picture. There could not have been an AddRef() on something that doesn't exist, and must not be a Release() on something that isn't there.

2b)

Some of the code you indicated by a comment in your example is very relevant, but can easily be inferred. You have a local raw pointer variable, pUnknown. In the absent code, you presumably use a COM call that obtains an interface pointer, implicitly AddRefs it, and fills in your raw pointer with the proper value to use it. This gives you the responsibility for one corresponding Release() when you are done with it.

Next, you set a member raw pointer variable (m_pUnknown) with this same value. Depending on the previous use of this member variable, you might have needed to call Release() with its former value before doing this.

You now have 2 raw pointers set to the value to work with this COM interface instance and responsibility for one Release() due to 1 implicit AddRef() call. There are two ways to deal with this, but neither is quite what you have in your sample.

The first, most straightforward, and proper approach (which others have correctly pointed out & I skipped passed in the first version of this answer) is one AddRef() and one Release() per pointer. Your code is missing this for m_pUnknown. This requires adding m_pUnknown->AddRef() immediately after the assignment to m_pUnknown and 1 corresponding call to Release() "someplace else" when you are done using the current interface pointer from m_pUnknown. One usual candidate for this "someplace else" in your code is in the class destructor.

The second approach is more efficient, but less obvious. Even if you decide not to use it, you may see it, so should at least be aware of it. Following the first approach you would have the code sequence:

```
m_pUnknown = pUnknown;
m_pUnknown->AddRef();
pUnknown->Release();
```

Since pUnknown and m_pUnknown are set the same here, the Release() is immediately undoing the AddRef(). In this circumstance, eliding this AddRef/Release pair is reference count neutral and saves 2 round trips into COM. My mental model for this is a transfer of the interface and reference count from one pointer to the other. (*With smart pointers it would look like newPtr.Attach( oldPtr.Detach() );* ) This approach leaves you with the original/not shown implicit AddRef() and needing to add the same  m_pUnknown->Release() "someplace else" as in the first alternative.

In either approach, you exactly match AddRefs (implicit or explicit) with Releases for each interface and never go to a 0 reference count until you are done with the interface. Once you do hit 0, you do not attempt to use the value in the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Avi Berger already posted a great answer, but here is the same thing stated another way in case it helps with understanding.

In COM, reference counting is done within the COM object.  The COM runtime will destruct and free an object whose reference count reaches `0`. (This might be delayed by some time from the point of the count hitting `0`).

Everything else is a convention.  The usual convention amongst C++ COM programmers is that raw interface pointers should be treated as *owning pointers*. This concept means that any time a pointer points to a COM object, the pointer *owns* that object.

Using this terminology, the object may have multiple owners at any one time, and the object will be destroyed when nobody owns it.

However, raw pointers in C++ don't have ownership semantics built in. So you have to implement it yourself by making function calls:

- Call `AddRef` on an interface pointer when that pointer takes ownership of an object. (You'll need to be aware of which Windows API functions or other library functions already do this, to avoid you doing it twice)
- Call `Release` on an interface pointer when that pointer is about to stop owning an object.

The benefit of smart pointers is that they make it impossible for you to forget to call `Release` when an interface pointer stops owning an object. This includes the following cases:

- Pointer goes out of scope.
- Pointer is made to stop pointing to the object, by using assignment operator.

---

So, looking at your sample code.  You have the pointer `m_pUnknown`. You want this pointer to take ownership of the object, so the code should be:

```
m_pUnknown = pUnknown;
m_pUnknown->AddRef();
```

You will also need to add code to your class destructor and your class assignment operator to call `m_pUnknown->Release()`.  I would **very strongly** recommend wrapping these calls in the smallest class possible (that is, write your own smart pointer and make `TestClass` have that smart pointer as a member variable). Assuming of course you don't want to use an existing COM smart pointer class for pedagogical reasons.

The call `pUnknown->Release();` is correct because `pUnknown` currently owns the object, and the pointer is about to stop owning the object due to the fact that it will be destroyed when the function block ends.

---

You may observe that it would be possible to remove both of the lines `m_pUnknown->AddRef()` and `pUnknown->Release()`. The code will behave exactly the same. However , it is better to follow the convention outlined above. Sticking to a convention helps yourself to avoid errors and it also helps other coders to understand your code.

To put it another way, the usual convention is to think of the pointer as having a reference count of either `0` or `1`, even though the reference counting is not actually implemented that way.

Comment: Thank you.  I will acknowledge that smart pointers do have their benefits.  The reason I am doing it this way and asking these questions is so that I can understand the underlying concepts and procedures.  All of you have provided great input and have helped a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

First, my apologies.  My attempt to simplify my code for the sake of clarity turned out to be misguided.  However, I believe my questions were answered.  If I may, I will summarize.

1) Any COM object that is assigned a value other than `NULL` needs to be immediately followed by `AddRef()` unless the `AddRef()` was implicitly handled (as is the case with some Windows API calls).

2)  Any reassignment of value to a COM pointer, assuming that the "before" value is not `NULL` must be immediately proceeded by `Release()`.  `AddRef()` would then by needed as mentioned in #1.

3) Any COM variable whose value needs to be preserved beyond its current scope requires that it have a reference count of at least 1 upon exiting its said scope.  This may mean that an `AddRef()` is required.

Would this be a fair summary?  Did I miss anything?

Comment: COM objects cannot be assigned `NULL`.  I think you are talking about interface pointers; and overcomplicating things